# Debugging module throw errors?

Tags: node.js

I just started messing with node.js and I'm already having problems, I have no idea how to even start debugging this..

```
>   npm install express jade socket.io

module.js:333
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-jar'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.24/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:15:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just use npm just install each package with a separate command

```
npm install express
npm install jade
npm install socket.io
```

On my computer it works.

My suggestion is to use the "package.json" file. In that file you can specify the libraries you need and it's going to download the dependencies for you.
For example

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Alvise Susmel <alvise@50pixels.com>",
    "dependencies": {
            "jade": "*",
            "express": "*",
            "socket.io": "*"
    }
}
```

and just execute

```
npm install
```

And **npm** will make all for you. It will create a "node_modules" where there are the dependencies.

Just create your js files in the same directory of "node_modules" and the dependencies will be all available to be included.

As you can see in the **package.json** file, near every dependency, there is a " * ", that means "all versions". If you want, you can set a specific version.

If you want to know more about this, that's a useful link: https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the commands I entered don't work, and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: thanks, but this is what im trying to solve now. why doesn't this stuff ever just work -_-

http://cl.ly/image/2R2W1j0H0G0g

any ideas?

Comment: try
"brew install node"
npm will be also installed

Comment: another useful video about npm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkWoaHOtGnk#t=111

Comment: i tried, none of it works, legit dont know where to go from here